# I ordered a product on saturday and it has been delivered as well

Tags: sentence-construction

> I **ordered** a product on saturday and it **has been** delivered as well

Is this sentence correct? I'm doubtful because I used and with past and present.

Comment: There is no problem using more than one tense in a sentence, if that is your question.

Comment: Yeah that is my question thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 5):

It isn't grammatically wrong to use more than one tense, but without additional context, there are things that don't make sense about this sentence and it may not be the most idiomatic way to say what you want.

"It has been delivered *as well*" - as well as what? As well as being ordered? Or are you trying to say that both things happened on the same day, Saturday? That would be a problem because either Saturday is in the past or the present.

If you're trying to express surprise how *quickly* the product was delivered after the order date, English speakers would probably say:

> I ordered a product on Saturday and it has been delivered *already*!

Comment: We could also say like this right? . I ordered someday and have already received it.

Answer (score 1):

<sup>Please view my answer as a supplement to @Astralbee's. Their answer is perfectly correct and useful. This answer, however, focuses on when we might use two different tenses or voices in a single sentence.</sup>

When two actions happen in sequence, [i.e. you order a product online, the product is delivered], it's appropriate to use the same *tense*

1. I **ordered** an item on Saturday and **it arrived** on the same day.
   [*Past simple, Past simple*]
2. Not only **did I order** the product on Saturday but **it also arrived** that same day.
   [*Past simple, Past simple*]

You can also write one action in the Active voice, and the other in the Passive voice.

3. I **ordered** a product on Saturday and **it was delivered** the next day.
   [*Past simple*, *Past simple passive*]
4. The product **I’d ordered** on Saturday **was delivered** yesterday.
   [*Past perfect, Past simple passive*]

When a finished action is connected to the present, you can use the Present perfect.

5. The product I **ordered** on Saturday, *has **just** been delivered*.
                                                               , *has **already** been delivered.*
   [*Past simple, Present perfect passive*]